# Opening Google Sheets sidebar with a range edit trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to popup a sidebar when a cell is edited in a sheet? Below code successfully launches an alert box based on that trigger but it will not do so with a sidebar...

The function `showSidebar()` works fine when triggered manually from the Run Function menu in Script Editor.

I suspect that it may be a limitation of HtmlService as replacing the `showAlert()` code below with one that utilizes HtmlService will also make it stop responding to onEdit triggers...

```
function onEdit(event) {
  testTrigger();
}

function testTrigger() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var editRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var editRow = editRange.getRow();
  var editCol = editRange.getColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange("C3:C");
  var rangeRowStart = range.getRow();
  var rangeRowEnd = rangeRowStart + range.getHeight()-1;
  var rangeColStart = range.getColumn();
  var rangeColEnd = rangeColStart + range.getWidth()-1;
  if (editRow >= rangeRowStart && editRow <= rangeRowEnd && editCol >= rangeColStart && editCol <= rangeColEnd) {

    showAlert(); // will work
    showSidebar(); // will NOT work

  }

}


function showAlert() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var result = ui.alert(
     'title',
     'message',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK);

}


function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Page')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

Comment: How about installing the OnEdit trigger to ``testTrigger()`` in order to use ``showSidebar()`` and removing ``function onEdit(event) {testTrigger();}``? You can see the document of Installable Triggers at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: @Tanaike  Totally right! Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.